# Clarification needed on how to show that a module over itself has a generator in Lang's text exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

For the following question came from Serge Lang's Undergraduate algebra text:

> Let $R$ be a ring. Show that $R$ can be viewed as a module over itself, and has one generator.

I am not sure what to exhibit as a generator for a ring acting on itself to make itself into a module.  The reason for this is Lang defines the concept of a generator in the context of an example:

> ($\textbf{example 2}$, pages 186-7) Let $M$ be a module and $v_{1},\dots ,v_{n}$ elements of $M$.  Let $N$ be the subset of $M$ consisting of all elements $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}v_{i}$ with $x_{i}\in R.$  Then $N$ is a submodule of $M$.
> Indeed $0=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 0v_{i}$, so $0\in N$.  If $y_{1},\dots ,y_{n}\in R,$ then 
>  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}v_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_{i}v_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}+y_{i})v_{i}$ is in $N$. 
>  Finally, if $c\in R$, 
> then $c(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}v_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n} cx_{i}v_{i}$ is in $N$, so we have proved that $N$ is a submodule.  It is called the submodule by $\textbf{generated}$ and we call $v_{1},\dots ,v_{n}$ $\textbf{generators}$ for $N$.

I tried to do the following:  If $R$ is a module over itself, and since assuming the ring $R$ has an additive identity element, then, we can define an endomorphic map $f:R\rightarrow R$, where for ran any $r\in R$, I can let $r=f(1)$ and use $r$ as the generator.  However, I am a bit confused after consulting: Abstract Algebra
A Comprehensive Introduction By John W. Lawrence, Frank A. Zorzitto, on pg 452, it gives a definition of homomorphism in the context of modules with further exposition:

> $\textbf{Definition:}$ If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M, N$ are $R-$modules, a mapping $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ is called $R-\textit{\textbf{module homomorphism}}$ or more briefly an $R-\textit{\textbf{map}},$ provided $\phi$ is a homomorphism between the underlying abelian groups $M, N$ and also satisfies 
> $\phi(av)=a\phi(v)$ for every $a\in R$ and every $v\in M$
> When $K$ is a field, a $K-$module homomorphism is nothing but a $K-$linear transformation.
> Every abelian group using addition is also a $\mathbb{Z}-$module, as already noted.  If $A,B$ are such abelian groups, the $\mathbb{Z}-maps$ from $A$ to $B$ coincide with the group homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$. Indeed, if $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ is a group homomorphism, a moment's reflection reveals that $\phi(nx)=n\phi(x)$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x$ in $A$.

They then goes on for two more paragraphs stating:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is an $A-$module, the $R-$maps $R\rightarrow M$ are easy to come by.  For any $a$ in $M$, the mapping $\phi_{a}:R\rightarrow M$ defined by $r\mapsto ra$ is an $R-\textit{\textbf{map}}$ by routine verification, and this accounts for all of them.  Indeed if $\phi:R\rightarrow M$ is an $R-\textit{\textbf{map}}$, put $a=\phi(1)$.  Then for every $r$ in $R$ we get $\phi(r)=\phi(r1)=r\phi(1)=ra$.
> We should note from the above that ring homomorphisms $R\rightarrow R$ are not same as $R-\textit{\textbf{map}}$ when the ring $R$ is viewed as a module over itself.  The requirement $\phi(rs)=r\phi(s)$ for a ring  homomorphism differs from the requirement $\phi(rs)=r\phi(s)$ for an $R-\textit{\textbf{map}}.$  If $\phi:R\rightarrow R$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\phi(1)=1,$ whenever $\phi$ is an $R-\textit{\textbf{map}},$ then $\phi(1)$ could be any elements of $R$.

After reading the above, I am not sure if I can let $a=1=f(1)$ or just let $a=f(1)$.  I am also assuming that Lang doesn't mean generator in the context of free modules since there is an exercises concerning that a few exercise after the stated exercise.  I should also note that in Rotman's Advanced algebra 2nd edition, on page 450, he writes:

> Every ring $R$, when considered as a left module over itself, is a free left $R-module$ (with basis the one-point set {1}).

I don't know what Rotman means by having a one-point set {1} as a basis?  Does he mean he can use 1 as a generator to get all other elements from the ring $R$ and hence any nonidentity element from the ring $R$ is in span({1}) and this holds true regardless if the ring $R$ is finite or infinite?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, $1$ will do. For every $r \in R$ you will have $r = r \cdot 1$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti is that independent of whether the ring is finite or infinite if making a ring into a module over itself.  I can use 1 because the ring is assume to be an additive abelian group which has the identity 1?

Comment: No, $1$ is the *multiplicative* identity, whose existence is assumed in the definition here.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti does that mean for modules, the ring acting on the abelian group, in this case acting on itself, always assumes to have a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti if it is not too much trouble, can you make your comment info an answer please.  I searched the site and did not find a similar question.

Comment: It seems you seek intuition. Modules over a ring $R\,$ generalize vector spaces over a field $F,\,$ e.g. $\,F = \Bbb R.\ $ A field is naturally a vector space over itself, the case $n=1$ of the ubiquitous vector space $F^n$ over $F,\,$ i.e. elements of $F$ may be viewed as (one-dimensional) vectors. Your example is a module analog of that.

Comment: Thanks @SethMai, but my comment is not answer-grade.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti ok ok, no problem.  Thank you for your clarifications in your comment.  :)

Comment: @BillDubuque are you saying a viewing a ring as module over itself is analogous to a field as vector space over itself?

Comment: @SethMai That is indeed what my prior comment says. When studying modules you should compare module theorems  to the analogous vector spaces cases to understand precisely what generalizes and what does not (as you should always do when trying to comprehend a theory that generalizes others - going back-and-forth between generalization and specialization is how one builds up intuition for such abstractions).

Comment: @BillDubuque since it is an analogy, it doesn't imply that when viewing ring as a module over itself, that the ring is of dimension one.  I think there is ambiguity when talking about the number of generators in a module or a ring which refers to the order of the module or the number of elements in it versus its dimension as a vector space.  It is not clear which one Lang has in mind for his exercise

Comment: @BillDubuque the order of a ring/group that are part of the module don't play any roles when discussing the size of a module then?

Comment: It's more than just an analogy - vector spaces are modules over fields (or division rings) - which are free modules. So the vector spaces are a special case of general module theory over rings.

Comment: @BillDubuque so modules are just vector space over a general rings.  We can talk about its dimension as a vector space over a ring.  The generators are then the modules basis element?  The question is confusing for me because I am not sure if that is what Lang meant in his example since he doesn't talk of free module in a later exercise and he doesn't talk about generators in that context or whether he means the same thing in that context.

Comment: @SethMai, (unital) modules over rings are rather more complicated than vector space - for instance, they need not have a basis.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti then thd generator of a module has to do with the order of the ring that acts on the additive abelian group or the order of the additive abelian group.  I am beginning to learn about modules, and I am not sure how notions of dimensions versus size as in # of elements in the module are related and how they relate to generators.